# "Out of Memory!"-error on Debian 8 when starting SonarQube installed from native package

Tags: jvm, debian, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have a fresh install of Debian 8 on a VM with 4GB RAM. I installed SonarQube (using the native package). When I try to start with the supplied script, the log says the following:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
JVM exited while loading the application.
GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
Exception in thread "main" GC Warning: Out of Memory!  Returning NIL!
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
*** Got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu.gcj.runtime.NameFinder while trying to print stack trace.
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I tried increasing the -Xmx and -Xms values in the start script to no effect.

Answer (score 5):

From your log it seems you're using default java aka gnu.gcj.

You should install [openjdk7](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openjdk-7-jdk) or [openjdk8](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/openjdk-8-jre)

You could select proper JVM in $SONAR_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf by editing wrapper.java.command property ie

```
# To use Java 7
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

# To use Java 8
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: Indeed GCJ is not supported : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements